# Loop through text boxes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, for-loop

I have a webpage with many textboxes that make table. Now i need to loop through them, take always first and second input, calculate, and put output to third and fourth...  5 + 6 input 7 + 8 output etc.

Logic is not a problem, just using for example:

```
for(i=1;i=<13/4;i+4)
```

Now I'm more of C# programmer but this is old project. I was given and code is  in VB.net. Now, I have to write it in VB.net too. So, can anybody help me or point me where to go, what to read in order to succeed?

edit, C# pseudocode:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=13;i+=4)
    {
        double value1 = Convert.ToDouble("TextBox" + i.ToString().Text);
        double value2 = Convert.ToDouble("TextBox" + (i+1).ToString().Text);
        double value3 = value1 + value2;
        ("txtTotalAmount" + (i+2).ToString().Text = (value1 + value2).ToString();
        ("txtPercent" +(i+3).ToString().Text = (value1/value3 * 100).ToString();
    }
}
```

VB converter output:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 13 Step 4
    Dim value1 As Double = Convert.ToDouble("TextBox" & i.ToString().Text)
    Dim value2 As Double = Convert.ToDouble("TextBox" & (i + 1).ToString().Text)
    Dim value3 As Double = value1 + value2
    (__InlineAssignHelper("txtTotalAmount" & (i + 2).ToString().Text, (value1 + value2).ToString()))
    (__InlineAssignHelper("txtPercent" & (i + 3).ToString().Text, (value1 / value3 * 100).ToString()))
Next
End Sub
```

Edit: At the end i made it like this and it works:

```
Protected Sub  btCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btCalculate.Click
Dim tb1 As TextBox
Dim tb2 As TextBox
Dim tb3 As TextBox


    Dim i As Integer


    For i = 37 To 53 Step 4
        Dim value1 As String = "textbox" + i.ToString()
        Dim value2 As String = "textbox" + (i+1).ToString()
        Dim value3 As String = "textbox" + (i+2).ToString()


        tb1 = PlaceHolder1.FindControl(value1)
        tb2 = PlaceHolder1.FindControl(value2)
        tb3 = PlaceHolder1.FindControl(value3)

        tb3.Text = Integer.Parse(tb1.Text) + Integer.Parse(tb2.text)

    Next     

End Sub
```

Where PlaceHolder1 is 
`<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">`

Thanks everybody for help.

Comment: Can you at least show your non working code? Or your C# code so that we can help to convert it in VB.Net. Help us to help you

Comment: you can use online tools to convert your c# code to VB.Net. Just google it find some awesome tools.

Comment: `i+4` is _so_ wrong.

Comment: `i+=4` would be a first step to make it better.

Comment: Why not use a C# to VB.NET (like [this](https://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) or [this](http://converter.telerik.com/)) converter for a first, rough translation?

Comment: I tried to convert here http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a stab but are you looking for this...
I think you need to call the actual controls so use the this.controls (or vb.net me.controls). I've created the code again for you, hopefully this should help you.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 13 Step 4
        Dim value1 As Double = Convert.ToDouble(TryCast(Me.Controls(("TextBox" & i).ToString()), TextBox).Text)
        Dim value2 As Double = Convert.ToDouble(TryCast(Me.Controls(("TextBox" & i + 1).ToString()), TextBox).Text)
        Dim value3 As Double = value1 + value2
        TryCast(Me.Controls(("txtTotalAmount" & (i + 2)).ToString()), TextBox).Text = (value1 + value2).ToString()
        TryCast(Me.Controls(("txtPercent" & (i + 3)).ToString()), TextBox).Text = (value1 / value3 * 100).ToString()
        '  (__InlineAssignHelper("txtTotalAmount" & (i + 2).ToString().Text, (value1 + value2).ToString()))
        '  (__InlineAssignHelper("txtPercent" & (i + 3).ToString().Text, (value1 / value3 * 100).ToString()))
    Next
End Sub
```

I have commented out the inlineassignhelper as tbh i dont know anything about them or what they do!

I converted with http://converter.telerik.com/ to give the C# code for you.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 13; i += 4)
    {
        double value1 = Convert.ToDouble(this.Controls(("TextBox" + i).ToString()) as TextBox.Text);
        double value2 = Convert.ToDouble(this.Controls(("TextBox" + i + 1).ToString()) as TextBox.Text);
        double value3 = value1 + value2;
        this.Controls(("txtTotalAmount" + (i + 2)).ToString()) as TextBox.Text = (value1 + value2).ToString();
        this.Controls(("txtPercent" + (i + 3)).ToString()) as TextBox.Text = (value1 / value3 * 100).ToString();
    }
}

//=======================================================
//Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
//Conversion powered by Refactoring Essentials.
//Twitter: @telerik
//Facebook: facebook.com/telerik
//=======================================================
```

Hth
Chicken

----Edit
Added trycast to procedures, I cant see why it would work any different, but after looking at some other forums other people have had simliar issues with getting controls based from string names.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helps me a lot :)

Comment: No worries glad to help :)

Comment: Well now im getting error:

Line 93: Dim value1 As Double = Convert.ToDouble(Me.Controls(("TextBox" & i).ToString()).Text)

Comment: Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'Text' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'.

Comment: Which Line? - I'm guessing one of your textboxes isnt actually a texbox? Is this a web project or winforms, out of interest?

Comment: Dim value1 As Double = Convert.ToDouble(Me.Controls(("TextBox" & i).ToString()).Text)

and its web project

Comment: Is "Textbox1" a textbox? If not you could try .Value instead of .Text

Comment: Yes TextBox was textbox but he has problem with .Text, i will try Value.

Comment: With Value it says the same, but now 'Value' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'.

Comment: I've added trycast to the procedure, have a go with that. Other people have similar issues too with getting controls based from string names.

Comment: Thanks a lot for Help, finally i made it :)

Comment: No problem glad you got it! If all done can mark as answered that would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

I have correct your c# code, use them its work for you.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i <= 13; i += 4)
        {
            double value1 = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)this.FindControl("TextBox" + i.ToString())).Text);
            double value2 = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)this.FindControl("TextBox" + (i+1).ToString())).Text);
            double value3 = value1 + value2;
            TextBox txt = (TextBox)this.FindControl(("txtTotalAmount" + (i + 2).ToString()));
            txt.Text = (value1 + value2).ToString();
            TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)this.FindControl(("txtPercent" + (i + 3).ToString()));
            txt1.Text = (value1 / value3 * 100).ToString();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double value1 = Convert.ToDouble("TextBox" + i.ToString().Text);
```

That won't compile in C# or VB. Is this what you intended?

```
Dim value1 As Double = Convert.ToDouble("TextBox" & i.ToString() & ".Text")
```

Fix the other occurrences accordingly, but I don't think a string is going to translate to a control.

Comment: I want to take value from textbox and convert it to double. Than use it for calculation and put output to other textbox.

Comment: Isn't there a grid control for web pages? Seems like that is what you need.

Comment: I'm not aware of that. It's just static html page with <table></table> and inside cells are asp:textbox(es).

Comment: There is a GridView if you can switch to .aspx